# Unable to locate a dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have following so far:

```
<div class="username-link-container" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="userlink-dropdown_1" data-dropdown="userlink-dropdown_1">
<div class="inline-block vertical-align username-container">
<span class="username pointer-cursor" style="min-width:133px; text-align:right;">
SJZS KLFR
<img class="arrow vertical-align pointer-cursor" src="/img/header/red_arrow.png">
</span>
</div>
<div id="userlink-dropdown_1" class="f-dropdown dropdown-contents open f-open-dropdown" aria-autoclose="false" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" data-dropdown-content="" style="position: absolute; left: -0.549927px; top: 55px;">
<a id="alinkManageAccount" href="/en/Home" target="_self">Manage Account</a>
<a id="alinkManageProxy" href="/en/abc/abc1/abc2">Manage Proxy</a>
<a id="alinkSignOut">Sign Out</a>
</div>
```

I need to get to Sign out option which is inside the dropdown.

I have this:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://ab.com/");

System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

driver.findElement(By.id("txt-username")).sendKeys("Username");
driver.findElement(By.id("pwd-password")).sendKeys("Passw0rd");
driver.findElement(By.id("login-widget-submit")).click();

Select droplist = new Select(driver.findElement((By) (By.className("username-link-container")).findElement((SearchContext) By.id("userlink-dropdown_1"))));
droplist.selectByValue("Sign Out");
```

I am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException` error.
Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` class will only work for the `select` elements. In this case, you would need to select the item from the dropdown "manually":

```
// open up the dropdown
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".username-link-container")).click();

// select option
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign Out")).click();
```

You might also need to *wait for the link to become clickable*:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);  
WebElement link = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("Sign Out")));
link.click();
```

Comment: It is now saying "TimeoutException: Timed Out after 15 seconds waiting for element to be clickable By.cssslector: sign out